JMeter freezes when attaching a large-sized base64 text on body data
I've been trying to attach a base64 encoded image (large size) to my POST body data but it freezes every time I tried to paste it. Any suggestion for a good practice of attaching base64 texts on POST methods?
Thank you
Attaching a base64 encoded text on the POST request's body data like:
{  "image": "{insert long base64 text here}" }
after pasting, the JMeter just freezes.

If the payload (data) is the only one you can store it in an external file and use __FileToString() function either in HTTP Request sampler directly (if you plan to use it once) or somewhere in User Defined Variables if you want to re-use it in multiple HTTP Request Samplers
In case of multiple payloads you can write the data into CSV file and use CSV Data Set Config

Can you try non-GUI mode of execution, by pasting the payload in jmx file and try using command line?
